# Cannot send jsp form details to database usingSpring JDBC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, servlets, jdbc

I created a form in jsp and tried to send the form details to database using Spring JDBC. I created a JSP form, a servlet file db_Servlet.java to take the data from form and db_Service.java which sends data to database.

When i run the project using tomcat, it gets stuck when creating object of db_Service class.
The below code is the servlet doPost method of db_Servlet.java.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("entered the servlet");
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        String ph = request.getParameter("phone");
        long phone = Long.parseLong(ph);
        String emailid = request.getParameter("emailid");
        customer c= new customer(name,phone,emailid);
        try {
            System.out.println("entered the try block");
            db_Service service = new db_Service();
            int result = service.addtodb(c);
            System.out.println(result);
            String title = "Thank you";
            String doctype = "<!doctype html public \"-//w3c//dtd html 4.0 " +
                    "transitional//en\">\n";
            out.println(doctype +
                    "<html>\n" +
                    "<head><title>" + title + "</title></head>\n" +
                    "<body>" +
                    "Thank you for wasting your precious time"
                    + " </body></html>"
            );
        }
        finally {
            out.close();
        }
    }
```

And the below is db_Service class

```
public class db_Service {
    public void addtodb(customer c){
        System.out.println("Entered the service");
        ApplicationContext context =
                new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");

        JDBCtemplate customerJDBCtemplate =
                (JDBCtemplate)context.getBean("JDBCtemplate");
        customerJDBCtemplate.create(c.getName(),c.getPhone(),c.getEmailid());
    }
}
```

The comment "entered the service" is not displayed after the comment "entered the try block"

Comment: Try to catch exception and printout the stacktrace.

Comment: i tried to print the stacktrace but it doesn't print anything

Comment: Than use a Debugger to find out what is happend

Comment: Please tell me you aren;t really using this code... This will lead to memory issues, strange to debug database issues etc. So unless you want that use the code you have, else properly use dependency injection.

Comment: @M.Deinum iam new to this, can you tell me which part of the code will get memory issues?

Comment: Your `addtodb` method. That will create a new context each time. As soon as you start writing something like `new ApplicationContext` or `new BeanFactory` step away from the keyboard and rethink .

Answer (score 2):

Could you try adding the customer method without using servlets, Something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
     db_Service  db = new db_Service();
     customer c = new customer();
     db.addtodb(c);
}
```

If above code doesn't work fine then there may be a issue in loading the schemas of spring in beans.xml of your code

Comment: i tried this and it worked, but when i take the customer object from servlet its not working

Comment: are you getting errors while saving like timout execptions?

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Spring, then it's better to use auto-wire rather than creating bean object manually. Try something like this:

```
@Autowire
db_Service service;
```

Also add required annotations like `@service` to your `db_Service` accordingly.

Comment: This should be a commetn not an answer